# How to trigger function dial.valueChanged.connect() only once the left mouse button is released?

Tags: python, arduino, pyqt, pyqt5, pyserial

### Background

I want to control a servomotor via a Python Gui (PyQt) component "**QDial**". Hopefully the servomotor should rotate "**simultaneously**" with the Dial in GUI.

[image]

Below is the related code:

**Arduino**

```cpp
void loop(){

   // while(!Serial){} //
   if(Serial.available()>0){        
       posOrder = Serial.readString(); // get Angle-Value from Serial
        
       // write to Serial Monitor 
        Serial.print("Set Servo Position to: ");   
        Serial.println(posOrder);

        int angle = posOrder.toInt();
        myservo.write(angle);    
        Serial.flush();
     
        delay(30);
    }
}
```

**QDial**

```
## ....some code...

   self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.writeToSerial)

## ...

def writeToSerial(self):  
    # create serial connection
    self.ser = serial.Serial(self.portPath, timeout=None, baudrate=self.baudRate)
      
    self.posAngle = self.dial.value()  # get value
    self.ser.write(str(self.posAngle).encode()) # write to Serial
```

### Problem

When I click on the tick of the Dial, it works pretty well. After click, the function `dial.valueChanged.connect(self.writeToSerial)` will call the function `writeToSerial()`, which has enough time to write dial value to the Serial. The serial monitor shows:

```
Set Servo Position to: 65
Set Servo Position to: 30
Set Servo Position to: 170
```

But when I rotate the dial **by holding the left mouse button**, the function `dial.valueChanged.connect(self.writeToSerial)` will be called in each small step. It means, the function `writeToSerial()` will be crazy frequently called and the `serial.write()` function can't write data in time. The serial monitor shows something like:

```
Set Servo Position to: 65666770717273747677
Set Servo Position to: 99100104108109114116119122126128130131133
Set Servo Position to: 1411421431441451461481501521541561
```

### Question

Is it possible to trigger function `dial.valueChanged.connect(self.writeToSerial)` only once the left mouse button is released? Or any other idea to solve this Problem？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to invoke `writeToSerial` when the mouse is released then you must use the [`sliderReleased`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#sliderReleased) signal:

```
self.dial.sliderReleased.connect(self.writeToSerial)
```

On the other hand, the problem is that you are not delimiting the strings so that when it is decoded you know when the information ends, for example if the end-line is used as a delimiter then you could obtain the data in the following way:

```py
self.ser.write("{}\n".format(self.posAngle).encode())
```

```cpp
posOrder = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
```

Comment: Nice answer! To the second approach. It works much better than before. But I can still see some posOrder in serial monitor like : Set Servo Position to: 4543, Set Servo Position to: 549.  Rarely appeared, but once appear cause the servo motor to wobble.

Comment: @sun0727 Perhaps a more complex protocol helps, or better simply verify that the data is valid, for example: `if(angle > 0 && angle < 180){ /**/}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, is it also possible to set the dial, that can only stepwise slide, e.g. 10°,  even if I slide it by holding the mouse button?

Comment: @sun0727 probably yes but that is a question that escapes from your original question so you must create another post